# Why does the recursion in JS does not follow proper order

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am learning recursive functions in JS. So far I have understood the logic behind recursion. I am following a certain tutorial with an example of Finding Factorial with a recursive function **factorial(x)**.

I am a bit confused from the example, why the last loop but one returns 1. I thought it should be **0 * 1 = 0** and not **1 * 1 = 1** considering the order of returns.

[image]

What is my misunderstanding?

Comment: If you look at the last `if` statement, you will see it does follow the correct order: you will never get 0 * 1 because 1 is returned _if_ the input is 0.

Comment: Your question is not really a programming question, but rather a maths question. See: [Prove 0!=1
from first principles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20969/prove-0-1-from-first-principles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the last recursive call, i.e. `factorial(0)`, you get 1 because of the base case that returns 1 if the `factorial` function is called with 0 as an argument.

The following base case

```
if (x == 0) {
   return 1;
}
```

executes when you call `factorial` function as: `factorial(0)`.

The function that initiates the last recursive call is `factorial(1)`, where `x` is 1.

So

```
return x * factorial(x - 1)
```

is actually

```
return 1 * factorial(0)
```

and as `factorial(0)` returns 1, `factorial(1)` returns

```
return x * factorial(x - 1)
```

which is

```
return 1 * 1
```

Following is how you can visualize different recursive calls and their return values:

```
factorial(3)
|   factorial(2)
|   |   factorial(1)
|   |   |   factorial(0)
|   |   |   return 1
|   |   return 1 * 1
|   return 2 * 1
return 3 * 2
```

Comment: so will it be correct to say that the real operation inside a recursive functions starts from the base condition then going upward to others. Because  factorial(1) will be completely evaluated after factorial(0) is finished been evaluated where our base condition is met. and factorial(2) will be evaluated after factorial(1) is evaluated. likewise factorial(3) will complete after factorial(2) is complete. Thanks

Comment: Yes, exactly. Recursive function keeps calling itself _until_ base condition is met and you return from a particular recursive call, like `factorial(0)` in your case returns 1.

Comment: Took me literally 5 seconds to find that duplicate...

Comment: Please stop trying to protect your answer and think of the good of the site. There are [literally thousands of questions about recursion and why the results are reversed](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+why+is+the+order+of+results+reversed+when+i+use+recursion). Find the one that matches *your* ideal duplicate of this question.

Comment: I think you fail to understand how answers work. If an answer explains how every step of recursion works, it answers this question. No, not every question related to recursion is a duplicate of every other question; luckily, that's a far cry from what I was arguing. Good try at a strawman argument though. We have a tremendous resource in Stack Overflow; millions of already-answered questions a few steps away from being utilized if only people would take a few moments to find them. Duplicates can be great signposts for those gems hiding away, but only if people take that time.